# Interivew: Sweet Candies

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

You have been provided the sweetness level of N candies placed in a row. The sweetness level of each candy is represented as an integer.
And yes, a candy can have negative sweetness level (it's bitter one :P).
You have to provide an output, an integer, which represents the maximum sum of sweetness you can attain by eating a **contiguous segment of the given candies.**

**Note:** if all the candies are bitter chose none and thus return 0

**Constraints**

N <= 10^5
Sweetness of any candy (Si): -10^3 <= Si <= 10^3

**Example**
**Input**
5
12 -10 17 -20 15
**Output**
19

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. We are not here to write you codes. We are here to help each other out. So to help you you need to provide the work that you've done until now and sharing the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This is very common algorithmic problem which can be solved in O(n) time.
Known as Maximum Subsequent Sum Problem.
You can read more about this [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/)

Comment: I wrote a simple brute force solution in 3 minutes in Python and it turned out to be exactly this.